# Maven pom sorting issue

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Hi guys working on a java maven project , where I have a modelVersion , but when i try to clean install the POM, POM gives me error stating that

```html
The xml element <modelVersion> should be placed before <parent>
```

Currently ,I have placed the modelversion before parent but still ,I am seeing the same error .

Pom:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-base-pom</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test.icdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-control-mcl-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <url>${dist.site.url}</url>


    <modules>
        <module>common-data-insertion</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <maven.buildNumber.skip>true
        </maven.buildNumber.skip>
        ......
    </properties>
```

Comment: A POM is a text document that can't give you an error. Explain exactly _where and how_ you get this error.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I ran into this error only when i run clean install (within intellij IDE) , it keeps on asking me to sort the pom file

Comment: is the model version missing in the parent file?

Comment: @Reinhold current pom is the parent pom and modelversion is present.

Comment: Why is there then a parent tag if it is the highest parent? Or is it just a parent?